Can we upload video file to appstore review reply?
I have uploaded new version of my app. But, They have rejected and they mentioned reason " the credentials which we gave to test are not working to login into app".
So, We have cross cross checked and same credentials are working fine.
So, In reply we just want to upload attach file of device recording , But it is showing following error while uploading.
An error has occurred. Try again later.
So, Anyone can help me, is there any restriction for video uploading (for size limit) or we can only upload only screenshots?

We did same, we replied them again with a video record of app login, will wait for their reply after this. Thank you for your quick reply.

It is seems appstore issue, after few minutes I have uploaded video successfully to reply.
